# Category in a hugo template

Tags: categories, hugo

how to show articles of a category in the homepage on hugo ?

I tried with this code but it doesn't work:

```
{{ range where .Site.RegularPages "Params.categories" "intersect" (slice "Motherboards") }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Categories and tags can be accessed through `.Site.Taxonomies`

Example

```
{{- range $taxonomy := .Site.Taxonomies.categories -}} 
    <a href="{{ .Page.RelPermalink }}">
        {{ $taxonomy.Name }}
    </a>         
{{- end -}}
```

You can see other examples in the documentation https://gohugo.io/templates/taxonomy-templates/#list-content-with-the-same-taxonomy-term